# Abort trap: While running Zoom web SDK on production server

Tags: webpack-dev-server, zoom-sdk, pure-js

When I run zoom web SDK on my production server at that time having this error

Script I am running is: `NODE_ENV=prod BABEL_ENV=development node corp.js --corp --https --host 0.0.0.0`

[image]

I tried to allocate memory as well by using below command:
`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" NODE_ENV=prod BABEL_ENV=development node corp.js --corp --https --host 0.0.0.0`

But issue remains same. Sometime "memory heap allocation" and sometimes only "abort trap"

Below is the production server detail
[image]